# ¿Cómo colocar sonido a las imagenes en un Slider?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código, el cual funciona como un carrusel de imágenes, cada 10 segundos las imágenes se intercambian automáticamente sin botones de avance o retroceso. Funciona muy bien.

Ahora necesito que cada vez que aparezca una imagen, suene el sonido correspondiente a cada imagen. Es decir, cuando aparezca la imagen perro, suene el audio perro.mp3, cuando aparezca la imagen pájaro, suene el audio pajaro.mp3 y así sucesivamente.

Las imágenes están en la carpeta drawable y en la carpeta raw los audios (perro.mp3, pajaro.mp3, etc)

No se como sincronizar las imágenes y los audios, imagino que debe ser con el indice (i) de las imágenes, pero no se como hacerlo.  Me pueden ayudar por favor

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewFlipper v_flipper;

MediaPlayer sonido;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int images[] = {R.drawable.pajaro, R.drawable.perro, R.drawable.gato, R.drawable.leon};
    int audios[] = {R.raw.pajaro, R.raw.perro, R.raw.gato, R.raw.leon};

v_flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.v_flitter);

// for (int i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {

//    sonido = MediaPlayer.create(this, audios[i]).start();

// }

for (int image: images) {

    flipperImages(image);
    
    MediaPlayer.create(this, audios[image]).start();

}

}


public void flipperImages(int image) {

  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
  imageView.setBackgroundResource(image);


  v_flipper.addView(imageView);
  v_flipper.setFlipInterval(10000);
  v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);

  v_flipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
  v_flipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes definir tus arreglos de imágenes y audios en la clase para que sean leídos por cualquiera de sus métodos.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewFlipper v_flipper;
MediaPlayer sonido;

int images[] = {R.drawable.pajaro, R.drawable.perro, R.drawable.gato, R.drawable.leon};
int audios[] = {R.raw.pajaro, R.raw.perro, R.raw.gato, R.raw.leon};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //int images[] = {R.drawable.pajaro, R.drawable.perro, R.drawable.gato, R.drawable.leon};
    //int audios[] = {R.raw.pajaro, R.raw.perro, R.raw.gato, R.raw.leon};
...
...
```

Ahora, como comentas puedes usar el indice para reproducir el audio y cargar la imagen, por ejemplo:

```
   public void flipperImages(int index) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(images[index]);


        v_flipper.addView(imageView);
        v_flipper.setFlipInterval(10000);
        v_flipper.setAutoStart(true);

        v_flipper.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
        v_flipper.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    }

   public void reproduceAudio(int index) {

        MediaPlayer.create(this, audios[index]).start();

    }
```

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys gracias por responder. Implemente las lineas y lo que me sugeriste, pero no me funciona. Al compilar pasa sin problemas y genera el APK, pero al instalar el archivo en el celular no funciona, intenta ingresar  a la app y se sale.